# How to turn on notification light at N4?

Tags: notifications, nexus-4

I have just bought a Nexus 4 and the notification light doesn't work. I have checked the display and put a tick on notification light but still no light.. even when I put it on charge the light doesn't come on. Does the notification light require the internet? I have a temporary problem with my internet line...

Answer (score 3):

Notification light turns only when there is a notification for say Facebook or Gmail etc not for charging and all.

There is no option of turning on the notification light at the time of charging in stock so if you need it then you can use [Light Flow](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rageconsulting.android.lightflowlite&hl=en)
It allows to put custom LED color at different events.